# Why does my calculator answer .1564 for cos(90)?

Tags: trigonometry, calculator

I know that cos(90) equals zero but my calculator gives .1564. Everything else but trig functions work properly on my calculator. It may be broken or I might have pressed a button the changes the value of trig functions. Does anyone know why my calculator gives this answer?

Comment: Your calculator is in gradients. Change it to degrees.

Comment: @Brent The spelling is "gradian", but good observation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculator is in radians mode. You need to change it to degrees mode.

Edit: gradians, not radians, but in any event it is not in degrees.

Comment: @Brent's comment was correct. The calculator is in gradians ("Grad") mode. Not radians ("Rad"). Please amend or delete your answer.

Comment: ahh thank you, which button do I press?/what is the symbol for it? I have a casio calculator btw

Comment: What's the model number?

Comment: fx-82MS I believe